# Can my employer adjust FICA contributions on payroll they have already processed?

Tags: united-states, taxes

After a sabbatical I joined my last employer as a person with resident tax status, married.

Before my sabbatical I worked for them as a person of non-resident tax status, single.

Since I forgot to give them the proper W4, they have processed my payroll last week without making the proper FICA contributions (non-residents don't pay FICA) or correct withholding.

If I give them the proper W4 now, will they be able to "go back" and make the proper FICA contributions and withholding?

My employer is a private company in CA that pays every two weeks.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask your employer. It is safe to assume that as long as the year hasn't ended they can adjust, but it may be problematic if they don't know **how** to do that. They might refuse, technically its your responsibility.

And its W9, not W4. W4 has nothing to do with FICA.

Comment: 1. If they refuse who pays the employer part of the FICA? 2. The W9 only asks for my SSN. What does it have to do with my resident and/or married status? Would that not be the W4?

Comment: 3. How do they do that? How/What information can I offer them to make it easier for them?

Comment: FICA has nothing to do with your marital status, and everything to do with your resident status. You certify your residency status on form W9.

Comment: "technically its your responsibility." It is NOT the employee's responsibility. The employer is responsible. http://www.irs.gov/publications/p15/ar02.html#en_US_2013_publink1000202531 "But you [the employer] are the one who owes the underpayment."

Comment: @user102008: but is not giving my employer the correct information *my* responsibility to begin with? Had I given them the right information in time, it would have been their responsibility, but in the OP you will notice that I delayed giving them that info out of carelessness.

Comment: @user providing the employer with the correct information is the employee responsibility. You can't say "don't take FICA form me", and then have the employer take the blame and pay penalties when in fact you should have been paying it. In fact there's a court decision about that exactly that I saw somewhere. I can look for it again if you insist.

Comment: @littleadv: But of course you can't just say "don't take FICA from me". I think that the employer must assume that FICA must be paid unless the employer gives a valid reason; and then, only assume that it lasts for as long as that reason exists. In this case, the OP was a F1/J1 non-resident, and he can normally only be non-resident for a limited number of calendar years. So if that is over, the employer should start deducting FICA again unless the employee gives a new reason. Anyway, from my reading of Publication 15, yes, it does seems that the employer is responsible.

Comment: @user102008 in this case the OP hasn't provided the employer with the correct information. Basically, although unintentionally, the employee lied about his legal status. While the employer is liable for everything after the OP corrected the report, I'm not sure if the employer can be kept liable for the periods the employee provided false info.